# how can I get the exact GPS coordinates and quickly?

Tags: android, gps

I defined the GPS coordinates.  I have created an application onLocationChanged - receives position. That works. Now I want to increase the speed of getting kordinaty and precision coordinate.

how can I get the exact GPS coordinates and quickly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read Reto Meiers "deep dive  into location":

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Short version:  you get what OS provides you not more or less

Comment: "In remaining free time I ride mountainbike in nearby forests." -respect;)

Comment: well, not only in nearby forests - I also go to the river: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv_uu_YOmE4

Comment: I'm also take a great interest this. By the way landscape similar to my home but you have more mountainous terrain

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you, try this :

```
 LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
 mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            mlocListener);



  public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            mAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        String cityName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
                .getLocality() : TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        String countryName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
                .getCountryName() : Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()
                .toString();


        mCurrentSpeed.setText(loc.getSpeed());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```